# There exists two of them such that their difference is divisible by --(n)--

Tags: probability

There are 7 arbitrarily chosen positive integers. the teacher said that " there exists two of them such that their difference is divisible by --(n)-- "unfortunately there was such a large noise at the end of the statement, that we cannot hear it exactly. so find what could be the value of --(n)-- to have correct sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Any $n\le 6$ works. If you spread seven integers among $n\le 6$ possible different remainders modulo $n$, then at least one remainder is used repeatedly.